# Alternative to RUBE or BodyEditor in libgdx

Tags: box2d, libgdx

Here I am trying simple game of basketball ,
Very first I have created circle shape balls to test box2d physics in libgdx .

[image]

now to integrate basketball image besides circle shapes what is the method.

besides using  BodyEditor and RUBE is there another way to do this..
just to replace circle with image i feel bodyEditor is the real lengthy method ..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one easy way come my mind is

Make a Sprite object.

```
Sprite sprite;

sprite.setposition(body.getx()-body.getwidth/2f ,body.gety()-body.getheight/2f);

sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
```

and dont forget to turn off the debug renderer

This is only a pseudo code not a proper syntax code. Just to give u a way to proceed